# Troubleshooting failure of importing oud schema on OpenDJ 3.0.0

Tags: opendj

I tried to import exiting schema from `Oracle Unified Directory (OUD)` into `OpenDJ 3.0.0` by following this: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/#importing-exporting-ldif

However after `import-ldif` was executed, I noticed following line.

```
category=PLUGGABLE seq=38 severity=INFO msg=Processed 100 entries, imported 0, skipped 80, rejected 20 and...
```

I am not sure why but it looks like no data is imported.

I ran following `ldapsearch` cmd afterward then following response was returned.

```
ldapsearch --hostname opendj.domain.com --port 389 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --baseDN "o=example org,c=us" "(uid=johndoe01)"

SEARCH operation failed
Result Code:  32 (No Such Entry)
Additional Information:  The search base entry 'o=example org,c=us' does not exist
```

When I inspect at oud schema ldif, first four lines are like below.

```
dn: o=example org,c=us
changetype: add
objectclass: organization
objectclass: top
```

I haven't found a clue yet but I like to know why base DN is missing even though I specified during the install process and why import operation was failed. I look forward to your advice.

Just fyi - During the install process, I selected `JE Backend` as backend type and provided `o=example org,c=us` as base entry dn. I didn't enclose the base DN with double quotes.

Comment: When importing, you can specify a file for rejected entries, and for skipped entries. There should be comments about why they get rejected. But generally, when there is no data imported, it's probably because of a mismatch between the data in LDIF, the server's configuration and possibly arguments in the command.

Comment: Some terminology issue: You say import oud schema. I assume you mean import data from OUD (using an export to ldif on OUD and import-ldif in OpenDJ). Was the schema data also migrated (if OUD had schema customizations, under config/schema)?

Comment: Morning, yes sir. I meant for import data from OUD. I was told we have existing OUD data in ldif format so that I don't have to export it on OUD. I will check with our OUD expert if schema data migrated. I greatly appreciate your advice! Have a good one!

Comment: I was told that 99-user.ldif from oud has some schema customization. I don't know what they are but will look into them.